# Getting error: Could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, testing, react-redux

This is the Login File, I think this is where my issue is coming from. I am a beginner in React and Redux, so this is where I am doing it.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Field from './Field'
import useStyles from './styles'
import styles from './Login.module.css'
import { GoogleLogin } from 'react-google-login'
import {useDispatch} from 'react-redux'
import { useHistory, Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { signup, signin } from '../../actions/auth'
import { Avatar, Button, Paper, Grid, Typography, Container } from '@material-ui/core'
import LockOutlinedIcon from '@material-ui/icons/LockOutlined'
import { createProfile } from '../../actions/profile'
import Google from './Google'
import { useSnackbar } from 'react-simple-snackbar'
import CircularProgress from '@material-ui/core/CircularProgress';



const initialState ={ firstName: '', lastName: '', email: '', password: '', confirmPassword: '', profilePicture: '', bio: ''}

const Login = () => {

    const classes = useStyles();
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState(initialState)
    const [isSignup, setIsSignup] = useState(false)
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const history = useHistory()
    const [showPassword, setShowPassword] = useState(false);
     // eslint-disable-next-line 
    const [openSnackbar, closeSnackbar] = useSnackbar()
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('profile'))
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
    
    const handleShowPassword = () => setShowPassword(!showPassword);
    const handleChange =(e)=> {
        setFormData( {...formData, [e.target.name] : e.target.value} )
    }

    const handleSubmit =(e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        if(isSignup) {
            dispatch(signup(formData, openSnackbar, setLoading))
        } else {
            dispatch(signin(formData, openSnackbar, setLoading))
        }
        setLoading(true)
    }


    const switchMode =() => {
        setIsSignup((prevState) => !prevState)
    }

    const googleSuccess = async (res) => {
        console.log(res)
        const result = res?.profileObj
        const token = res?.tokenId
        dispatch(createProfile({name: result?.name, email: result?.email, userId: result?.googleId, phoneNumber: '', businessName: '', contactAddress: '', logo: result?.imageUrl, website: ''}))

        try {
            dispatch({ type: "AUTH", data: {result, token}})

            window.location.href='/dashboard'
            
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
    const googleError =(error) => {
        console.log(error)
        console.log("Google Sign In was unsuccessful. Try again later")
    }


    if(user) {
      history.push('/dashboard')
    }

    return (
        <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
      <Paper className={classes.paper} elevation={2}>
        <Avatar className={classes.avatar}>
          <LockOutlinedIcon />
        </Avatar>
        <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">{ isSignup ? 'Sign up' : 'Sign in' }</Typography>
        <form className={classes.form} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <Grid container spacing={2}>
            { isSignup && (
            <>
              <Field name="firstName" label="First Name" handleChange={handleChange} autoFocus half />
              <Field name="lastName" label="Last Name" handleChange={handleChange} half />
            </>
            )}
            <Field name="email" label="Email Address" handleChange={handleChange} type="email" />
            <Field name="password" label="Password" handleChange={handleChange} type={showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'} handleShowPassword={handleShowPassword} />
            { isSignup && <Field name="confirmPassword" label="Repeat Password" handleChange={handleChange} type="password" /> }
          </Grid>
          <div className={styles.buttons}>
               <div>
                    {/* <button className={styles.submitBtn}> { isSignup ? 'Sign Up' : 'Sign In' }</button> */}
                    {/* <ProgressButton>{ isSignup ? 'Sign Up' : 'Sign In' }</ProgressButton> */}
                    {loading ? <CircularProgress /> 
                    : 
                    <button className={styles.loginBtn} >{ isSignup ? 'Sign Up' : 'Sign In' }</button>
                    }
                    
                </div>
                <div> 
                    <GoogleLogin
                    clientId = {process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID}
                    render={(renderProps) => (
                        <button className={styles.googleBtn} onClick={renderProps.onClick} disabled={renderProps.disabled} ><Google /> Google</button>
                    )}
                    onSuccess={googleSuccess}
                    onFailure={googleError}
                    cookiePolicy="single_host_origin"
                />
                </div>
          </div>
          <Grid container justifyContent="flex-end">
            <Grid item>
              <Button onClick={switchMode}>
                { isSignup ? 'Already have an account? Sign in' : "Don't have an account? Sign Up" }
              </Button>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        <Link to="forgot"><p style={{textAlign: 'center', color: '#1d7dd6', marginTop: '20px'}}>Forgotten Password?</p></Link>
        </form>
      </Paper>
    </Container>
    )
}

export default Login
```

This is the Testing File

```
import React from 'react';
import {render,screen, cleanup} from '@testing-library/react'
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
// file imports
import user from '../../../../server/controllers/user'
import Login from '../Login/Login'

test("should render Login Component",()=>{
    render(<Login />);
    const linkElement = screen.getByText(/Google/i);
    expect(linkElement).toBeInTheDocument();
})
```

I am getting this error

```
● should render Login Component

    could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>

      23 |     const [formData, setFormData] = useState(initialState)
      24 |     const [isSignup, setIsSignup] = useState(false)
    > 25 |     const dispatch = useDispatch()
         |                      ^
      26 |     const history = useHistory()
      27 |     const [showPassword, setShowPassword] = useState(false);
      28 |      // eslint-disable-next-line
```

Should I wrap my code in a provider, if yes, where should I?

PS: I was thinking of wrapping it with a provider on the Login return function.

Comment: Please wrap your parent component by `Provider` with your redux `store`. `import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { store } from './redux/store'; ` and then `<Provider store={store}><Your component /></Provider>`

Comment: Could be a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66615280/could-not-find-react-redux-context-value-please-ensure-the-component-is-wrapped

Comment: Could be a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61934832/error-could-not-find-react-redux-context-value-please-ensure-the-component-is